# amcharts Accessing data in an XY series chart

Tags: amcharts

Is it possible to access the data through a chart series on an XY chart?

I'm sure that's an easy way to do this, but I'm not finding it.

I'm loading my data through a json and parsing it.

```
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
chart.dataSource.url = "/data/myData.json";
chart.dataSource.parser = new am4core.JSONParser();
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once series finishes loading its external data, it will set its own `data` property with it. So it will become accessible via `series.data`.

However, loading operation is asynchronous, meaning that it will not become available immediately after your code above executes. So you can use events to know precisely when it becomes available.

```
series.dataSource.events.on("done", function(ev) {
  console.log(series.data);
});
```